# BioSentVec Embedding not loading on Linux server

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, word-embedding, fasttext, bad-alloc

Python code in trial.py:

```
import sent2vec

model_path = 'BioSentVec/BioSentVec_PubMed_MIMICIII-bigram_d700.bin'

model = sent2vec.Sent2vecModel()

try:

    model.load_model(model_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

run at command line:

```
$ python3 trial.py
```

Output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'   
what():  std::bad_alloc 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

BioSentVec embedding is 22GB and I have 46GB available. Model based on fasttext.      Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Using conda environment - had problems with installing some dependencies that were older versions.
Any help with getting the embedding to convert sentences into vectors would be appreciated,
thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error that may be caused by insufficient addressable memory.

Note that a 22GB file-on-disk *might* take far more free memory than 22GB to load - so trying a machine with even more RAM might resolve the issue.

You should also double-check that the model file you have locally hasn't been truncated or corrupted in any way. Sometimes those problems show up as mysterious loading errors later.

(It seems the project [providing that file](https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/BioSentVec) hasn't provided an exact expected size. So I queried the web server with the command `curl -I "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/lu/Suppl/BioSentVec/BioSentVec_PubMed_MIMICIII-bigram_d700.bin"`, which reported:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Jun 2021 18:02:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Oct 2018 15:34:20 GMT
ETag: "53ba885aa-578beded2028f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 22475736490
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: RANGE, Cache-control, If-None-Match, Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, Content-Range, Content-Type
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

So given that `Content-Length` header, you should double-check that your local copy is exactly `22,475,736,490` bytes long.

Another option could be to try downloading it again to a different place – different path, or another machine with an impeccable internet connections – just to check both downloads have identical sizes and checksums.)

Comment: Thanks man, how would I check if it has been truncated or check how much load memory I need? Thanks again?

Comment: Sometmes the provider of large files will declare their exat intended size, or a checksum/hash for the full file, so users can check their local copies for any alterations comparison. I don't see such numbers at the project that seems to have originated your files (https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/BioSentVec), so I'll add an alternate way to learn the expected size to the answer.

Comment: 40 GB is more than enough for BioSentVec. It loads and runs the example from the repo on my 32GB RAM desktop, even without GPU.